# what is a better db table relationship design

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have a set of tables that descibe checklists, and their list of attributes (questions).  Attributes can be shared between checklists, which is why I have the CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE table.  When someone starts an instance of a checklist, a query is perfomed to get the current questions and then these are inserted into an answer table.  Now we want to display the checklists but group the attributes by a category.  Here is what I have before this requirment, hopfully I have included all pertenent columns.

```
CHECKLIST_CLASS
    CL_CLASS_ID
    CL_VERSION

ATTRIBUTE
    ATTRIBUTE_ID
    DESCRIPTION

CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE
   CL_CLASS_ID
   ATTRIBUTE_ID

CHECKLIST_INSTANCE
   CL_INSTANCE_ID
   CL_CLASS_ID

ANSWER
   CL_INSTANCE_ID
   ATTRIBUTE_ID
   VALUE
```

Once a checklist has been instantiated and we modify the checklist (revision it) the instantiated checklists must still reference the original questions. The way I display an instance of a checklist is I query the ANSWER table with a JOIN to the ATTRIBUTE table and iterate over the results set.

Obviously I'll add a Category table

```
 ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY
   AC_ID
   DESCRIPTION
```

But where do I add the refence to this table? If I add the AC_ID to the CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE definition table, then I think I have two options from here.

1) Also modify the ANSWER table to include the AC_ID when the checklist instance is built.

```
ANSWER
   CL_INSTANCE_ID
   ATTRIBUTE_ID
   VALUE
  *AC_ID*
```

2) Or leave the ANSWER table alone and when I query it for displaying, do some JOINS to get the AC_ID from the CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE table. I know the ANSWER.CL_INSTANCE_ID, so JOIN the CHECKLIST_INSTANCE table to get the CL_CLASS_ID and then use this along with the ANSWER.ATTRIBUTE_ID to get the AC_ID from the CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE table.

What is a more sound design?  Or are there other options I'm not considering? I don't want to just add the AC_ID to the attribute table because then the attribute and category is coupled.  Attributes can be shared between checklists so that ultimately we roll up metrics based on metrics regardless of which checklist class it was found on.

i.e  How many dimensions were incorrect, could be on the Cabinet Blueprint Review Checklist as well as the Interior Room Framing Layout Review Checklist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `AC_ID` in `CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE` and a new `CATEGORY` table is sound design. Adding `AC_ID` in `ANSWER` is not bad either, it leads to fewer joins although it could introduce some integrity problems (the answer category and the question category could be different), but nothing that a check cannot solve.

An alternative that comes to mind is handling the category as a special case of checklist item that can link to other checklist items. This is specially handy if your usecase requires having nested categories (it is not clear if you do).

```
CHECKLIST_TO_ATTRIBUTE
  CL_CLASS_ID
  ATTRIBUTE_ID
  CL_TYPE -- (tells if this is a plain checklist or a category)
  PARENT_CL_ID  -- (points to the parent category checklist item, NULL if this is a top level category)
```

Comment: the integrity problem is what made me think of just doing the joins.  But I think I'd rather take my chances and make it easier to query.